# Reshaping list dataframe with combination of character and numeric values to tibble or matrix

Tags: r

Through a rather large safely() function in R, I create a dataframe that consists of a combination of "NA" and numeric values.  The NAs result when there is an empty result from the safely function.  Ultimately I end up with a data that I call "temp".  See below:

```
as.data.frame(temp)
     V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7        V8        V9        V10        V11         V12
1    NA NA NA NA NA NA NA        NA        NA         NA         NA          NA
2    NA NA NA NA NA NA NA        NA        NA         NA         NA          NA
3  0.75  1 10  6  7  3  2 0.1531668 0.1369553 0.06986474 0.06417629 -0.08044641
4    NA NA NA NA NA NA NA        NA        NA         NA         NA          NA
5    NA NA NA NA NA NA NA        NA        NA         NA         NA          NA
6    NA NA NA NA NA NA NA        NA        NA         NA         NA          NA
7    NA NA NA NA NA NA NA        NA        NA         NA         NA          NA
8    NA NA NA NA NA NA NA        NA        NA         NA         NA          NA
9  0.75  1 20  6  7  3  2 0.1531668 0.1369553 0.06986474 0.06417629 -0.08044641
10   NA NA NA NA NA NA NA        NA        NA         NA         NA          NA
11   NA NA NA NA NA NA NA        NA        NA         NA         NA          NA
12   NA NA NA NA NA NA NA        NA        NA         NA         NA          NA
13   NA NA NA NA NA NA NA        NA        NA         NA         NA          NA
14   NA NA NA NA NA NA NA        NA        NA         NA         NA          NA
15 0.75  1 10  8  7  3  2 0.1492299 0.1369553 0.05290161 0.05341882 -0.08897615
16   NA NA NA NA NA NA NA        NA        NA         NA         NA          NA
17   NA NA NA NA NA NA NA        NA        NA         NA         NA          NA
18   NA NA NA NA NA NA NA        NA        NA         NA         NA          NA
19   NA NA NA NA NA NA NA        NA        NA         NA         NA          NA
20   NA NA NA NA NA NA NA        NA        NA         NA         NA          NA
21 0.75  1 20  8  7  3  2 0.1492299 0.1369553 0.05290161 0.05341882 -0.08897615
22   NA NA NA NA NA NA NA        NA        NA         NA         NA          NA
23   NA NA NA NA NA NA NA        NA        NA         NA         NA          NA
24   NA NA NA NA NA NA NA        NA        NA         NA         NA          NA
```

And here is a truncated summary of the structure:

```
> str(temp)
List of 288
 $ : chr "NA"
 $ : chr "NA"
 $ : num 0.75
 $ : chr "NA"
 $ : chr "NA"
 $ : chr "NA"
 $ : chr "NA"
```

The problem I'm having is unlisting data.  I think that I'm creating a dataframe, but as you can see from the str(), it is still as a list.

Ultimately I want to have a tibble, matrix, or dataframe that is simply a table and eliminates the nested lists.  I think that I need to somehow reduce the "list of 288" down to a basic vector, and then construct a tibble, matrix, or dataframe, but I think an issue is arising with the combination of having numeric values with characters (i.e. NAs).  I would like to have an intermediate table that preserves the NA rows so that I check some results, but ultimately I'll delete the rows with NAs.  I've tried using drop_na() but am getting errors that I believe is due to the structure of "temp".

Therefore, my goal is create a tibble, matrix, or dataframe that retains rows 3, 9, 15, and 21 from the original table in this post.  But the row numbers won't be consistent so I can can't just use slice or some similar function.  And I think my primary problem is the structure of temp.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Good question.  When I do that  the structure is the "List of 288" that I reference in my question.  Which is weird to me too.

Comment: I may have figured it out though.  Would this work: s <- unlist(as.matrix(temp)), then
tempmatrix <- matrix(s, nrow = 24, ncol = 12), then tempdf <- data.frame(tempmatrix).  So convert to matrix, unlist, then convert back to a matrix, and then to a dataframe.  It's convoluted, but it seems to work.

Comment: Yeah, I did save it as temp first.  But the methodology for how I got to temp is somewhat complex and I was trying to simplify the question.  If I just do as.data.frame(temp) alone it won't work.  But  if I do the few steps I suggest in my 2nd comment above it works. So I believe I have figured it out.  I'll post that in the "Answer Your Question" link.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have figured out an answer to my own question.  It seems to work if I convert temp to a matrix and unlist the matrix.  Then redefine it as a matrix with a specific number of columns.  Then it can be converted to a data.frame if that is desired.  So the code would be:

```
s <- unlist(as.matrix(temp))
tempmatrix <- matrix(s, nrow = 24, ncol = 12)
tempdf <- data.frame(tempmatrix)
```